# Was the Accession War common knowledge in Skyrim in 4E 201?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

In *Dragonborn*, one of the possible dialog options implies that the Last Dragonborn is ignorant of the Argonians having invaded Morrowind. I find this problematic for a number of reasons:

- The Accession War took place in 4E 6, which is quite a long time before the events of *Skyrim*.
- The widespread availability of books, and the use of written journals even by bandits, strongly implies a high literacy rate, and I would expect this to be accompanied by some sort of general education as well.
- The Red Year seems to be known to the bards of the Bards College, as well as the people of Windhelm.
- If the Last Dragonborn is Argonian, the dialog does not acknowledge this fact, which suggests that the Dunmer no longer consider it a recent event (i.e. they don't get offended or upset by the Last Dragonborn's ignorance, or indeed their very presence on Solstheim), but just a general piece of history that anyone might know. Similarly, there are no apparent racial tensions between the Argonians and Dunmer in Windhelm.

The obvious explanation is that the writers put this in as a sort of clumsy exposition in case the player didn't do Brand-Shei's quest already (or wasn't paying attention to the lore in said quest). On the other hand:

- Nobody *else* ever mentions it, as far as I can remember. Before the player arrives on Solstheim, nearly all discussion of Morrowind involves the eruption of the Red Mountain.
- Brand-Shei has good reason to specifically research Morrowind's history, given his uncertain origins.
- The Bards College are a bunch of bards. Knowing about history is literally their entire job (well, that and the actual singing).
- Windhelm was affected by a large stream of Dunmer refugees, so of course they know where the Dunmer came from and why.
- Skyrim is much closer to Vvardenfell than to Black Marsh. The Nords might only care about history in their immediate vicinity, or when it directly affects them (e.g. the Great War).

**Did "most people" in Skyrim know about the Accession War in 4E 201?**

Comment: You find "that the Last Dragonborn is ignorant of the Argonians having invaded Morrowind" problematic? And that he can be ignorant about Divines or Daedra is OK? I would be more surprised if a war from nearly 200 y. ago was obvious. Out of universe all this is for player's convenience and isn't supposed to suggest much.

Comment: @Mithoron: It is unrealistic to expect everyone to know everything about mystical subject matter, especially in Skyrim where such things are shunned as a matter of course. OTOH, I would expect a real person to be familiar with (for example) the Mexican-American war, at least in general terms.

Comment: Umm, Oblivion Crisis was **much** bigger war with Dagon, and yet we can ask in game who he is...

Comment: @Mithoron: *Shrug* - This question is about the Accession War. If you want to talk about the Oblivion Crisis, I would humbly suggest you ask a separate question, or write an answer linking the two.